# How can I change the orientation of a buttons in a stack layout in Kivy

Tags: python, button, orientation, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class mylayout(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(mylayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(10):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), width=40, size_hint=(None, 0.15), orientation= 'lr-bt')
            self.add_widget(btn)


class NameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mL = mylayout()
        return mL

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NameApp().run()
```

I have attempted to  change the orientation here, but the orientation displayed on the app is still as if it were default

Comment: What exactly is the orientation of a button? Do you mean the orientation of the stacklayout?

Comment: yes I do, just changed the Q now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orientation is a property of the layout, not of the widgets it contains. You can use

```
self.orientation = "lr-bt"
```

in the `__init__` function to assign the property to the layout. You could also assign it in the appropriate .kv file if you use that.

Comment: ".kv file if you use that" - there should be no "if" there. If you're not using kv lang, then you're not using Kivy right. ;)

Comment: Generally you are right. But sometimes it still makes sense to do things in python that could be in the kivy file. Maybe `mylayout` is currently not styled in the kv file so setting the layout in the init may be appropriate. But generally of course kv files are great.